# Pandas: Aggregating with pivot_table or groupby silently drops columns of mixed type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This is perhaps known/expected behavior, but I found the following unexpected: Aggregating with pivot_table or groupby silently drops columns of mixed types boolean/numeric while `DataFrame.sum` (or `np.sum` on list of mixed types) do not:

`np.sum` and `pandas.DataFrame.sum` both return the value I would expect from summing over boolean and numeric values.  Is this intended behavior for groupby/pivot_table?

Example:

```
np.sum([0,False])
```

returns 0 and

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['t1','t1','t2'],'a':[1,23,4], 'b':[0,False,1]})
df.head()
```

[example table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaunT.png)

```
df.sum()
```

returns:

```
type    t1t1t2
a           28
b            1
dtype: object
```

as I would expect.

However,

```
pd.pivot_table(df,columns=['type'], aggfunc=np.sum, values=['a','b'])
```

Appears to silently drop column b: [output table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIn4Z.png)

as does

```
df.groupby('type').sum()
```

[output table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QljNi.png)

Comment: `df.groupby('type').agg({'a': 'sum', 'b': 'sum'})` will yield the expected result.